# Absolute positioning in TikZ3

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

> I am also submitting the solution, please, save your time and energy on this Question.

My problem is this. The absolute positioning stopped to work in some cases after upgrading TikZ2 to TikZ3. This is the code where I expected a square on the top of the page (picture on left), but I have got something different (picture on right). How can we fix it in TikZ3?

```
%! pdflatex or xelatex or lualatex
%! bug0002-problem.tex
%! running it twice
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\addtolength{\hoffset}{-1in}
\addtolength{\voffset}{-1in}
\usepackage{tikz} % version 3
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\node[minimum width=4cm, minimum height=4cm, draw, fill=orange, anchor=north] at (current page.north) {Hello World!};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: example 1]

Comment: Just a data point: in the current TeXLive 2013 (using LuaLaTeX) the given example without `\addtolength` compiles and produces the expected output of a rectangle at the top and centered on the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is no need to explicitly express how happy I was when I saw all the new features in TikZ3 and how unhappy I was when the key feature (for me) stopped to work properly from time to time.

My first solution is obvious from the code itself: comment out `\addtolength{\hoffset}{-1in}` and `\addtolength{\voffset}{-1in}`. It wasn't that simple to track it down in a real project and it wasn't possible for me to use such a solution when the page mirror was set long time ago. This is the code.

```
%! pdflatex or xelatex or lualatex
%! bug0002-solution-a.tex
%! running it twice
% This solution works in xelatex!
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
%\addtolength{\hoffset}{-1in}
%\addtolength{\voffset}{-1in}
\usepackage{tikz} % version 3
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\node[minimum width=4cm, minimum height=4cm, draw, fill=orange, anchor=north] at (current page.north) {Hello World!};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I needed another solution and I've found one: let's return the `\hoffset` and `\voffset` dimensions to their initial values but only in all the `tikzpicture` environments as TikZ3 is clearly using them for calculations. Please try this example where I used `\tikzset` and modified the style of `every picture`:

```
%! pdflatex or xelatex or lualatex
%! bug0002-solution-b.tex
%! running it twice
% This solution does not work in xelatex!
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\addtolength{\hoffset}{-1in}
\addtolength{\voffset}{-1in}
\usepackage{tikz} % version 3
\begin{document}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={execute at begin picture={
   \hoffset=0pt
   \voffset=0pt
   }}} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\node[minimum width=4cm, minimum height=4cm, draw, fill=orange, anchor=north] at (current page.north) {Hello World!};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I believe there is more going on as this solution does not work in `xelatex`, but it does in `pdflatex` and `lualatex`. We can easily compare the expected (picture on left) and the actual output from `xelatex` (picture on right). My answer is opening a subquestion, I am afraid. How can that be fixed in TikZ3?

[image: example 2]

Comment: Tampering with `\hoffset` and `\voffset` in LaTeX can lead to unexpected results and their value shouldn't be modified.

Comment: @egreg I know, I know, but this is an emergency solution inside the `tikzpicture` environments from an emergency situation. I am looking forward for a better solution or a patch.